# Why PHP ajax call is taking too long time to response if the upload image is big (8M)?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am validating a form with upload field using PHP, jQuery/Ajax call.

Now If the uploaded file size is big (Now it's 8MB) then it's taking too long time( just see it's taking 3.7 mins ) to response!!!

[image]

I don't understand why it's taking much time!

**jQuery/Ajax Code:**

```
$('#register').submit(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();        
    var formData = $('form').get(0);    
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST', 
        dataType : 'html',
        data: new FormData(formData),
        url : 'process/ccroipr-cat-p.php', 
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend : function () {
            $('#result').html( 'Please wait...' );
            $('#registerButton').prop('disabled', true);
        },
        success : function ( result ) {            
            $('#registerButton').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#result').html( result );
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP Code:**

https://codeshare.io/GqQNwq

Register Page link:

ccroipr.org/register.php

Comment: When you hit F12 in Firefox, you can see the timings of your requests. You can then find out where the problem might lie.

Comment: @BartFriederichs let me check it firefox.

Comment: The picture shows that the sending is slow?

Comment: What's the confusing part? If you need to transmit a large amount of data between the client and server (in either direction) and / or process a lot of data (e.g. whatever your validation code might do) your request will take longer.

Comment: @Chris if the file size is less than 5MB or equal then it's don't take much time !

Comment: @BartFriederichs I checked the but still don't' understand. can you check it please: http://ccroipr.org/register.php?

Comment: @ShibbirAhmed, that's information that should be _included in your question_. Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris I just updated it :(

Comment: What's in the server logs?